# Flexbox / Angular Material - Full width rows wrapped

Tags: angularjs, css, layout, flexbox, angular-material

I am using Angular Material, which makes use of Flexboxes. 
I would like to wrap boxes so that they spread across several rows. I am actually successfully doing this with the following code :

```
   <div layout="row" layout-align="start start" layout-wrap layout-margin>
      <md-card ng-repeat="SOME ITERATION" flex>
        SOME CONTENT
      </md-card>
   </div>
```

However rows are not filled completely. The `<md-cards>` don't strech until filling the whole space available in one row.

Here is a visual representation of what I would like to do :

[image]

`<md-cards>` would be the orange boxes, and they would fill the whole space on each available row.

Any suggestion about how to implement this with Flexboxes (if possible) is most welcome !